# буквенный поиск в vector

Tags: c++, c++builder

При создании кнопки поиска компилятор выдает ошибку:

> Lvalue required

Ругается он на эту строчку:

```
Search.name =  EditSearch->Text.c_str();
```

Полный код кнопки:

```
page search;
vector <page>::iterator p;
Search.name =  EditSearch->Text.c_str();
p= find(doc.begin(), doc.end(), search);
y = p - doc.begin();
Show();
```

Show - функция которая выводит данные ячейки вектора.
Задумка такая: через итератор ищем слово по индексу "y" если такое слово есть то программа нам выдает всю ячейку по этому индексу.

Comment: что такое Search.name? Ошибка говорит о том, что скорее всего вы пытаетесь присвоить значение константе

Comment: Тип данных вектора это структура состоящая из массивов, типом данных этих массивов является char. name это один из массивов. Я хочу присвоить search набранное слово из поля edit чтобы в дальнейшем произвести поиск в векторе.

Comment: @Sokol, дайте фидбэк - у Вас получилось? Или еще какие-то вопросы остались?

Comment: Программа перестала ругаться, но результат не тот который я ожидал, я даже не могу понять почему.... строчка

Comment: строчка y = p - doc.begin(); возвращает мне последнюю запись(ячейку в векторе). Хотя по задумке должен был вернуть мне ту ячейку в которой находится набранное слово...

Comment: У меня ощущение, что с функцией find что-то не так.... Но скорее всего руки у меня не с того места

Comment: @Sokol, посмотрите в сторону ```std::find_if```.

Comment: Укажите типы, без них Вам тяжело подсказывать. Например, что такое page,  doc?

Comment: @isnullxbh struct page{
  char name[70];
  char first_character[100];
  char genre[20];
    char  duration[8];
    char year[4];


};
  int extern x,y;
extern vector <page> doc;  page - это тип данных, doc- это вектор

Comment: @Sokol, обновил ответ, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const wchar_t* src_str = EditSearch->Text.c_str();
std::memcpy(Search.name, src_str, std::wcslen(src_str) * sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Способ от @freim'a:

```
std::wcscpy(Search.name, src_str);
```

**UPD.:**

```
auto it = std::find_if(doc.cbegin(), doc.cend(), [&search](const auto& _page) {
    return /* тут Ваше условие */;
});
```

Comment: теперь он ругается на строку: const char* src_str = EditSearch->Text.c_str(); ошибка :Cannot convert 'wchar_t *' to 'const char *'

Comment: @Sokol, так это к Вам вопросы - "EditSearch->Text.c_str()" - из Вашего кода. Укажите типы переменных, которые Вы используете.

Comment: Там нужно wchar_t, а не char.

Comment: Ребята, если ставите минус - объясняйте, почему, пожалуйста. Конструктивная критика приветствуется :)

Comment: Я + поставил. :) Все у вас правильно, только надо `wchar_t`, и длину строки считать как `wcslen(...)*sizeof(wchar_t)`. Не ваша вина, но поправьте все равно.

Comment: @freim, согласен. Но типы ТС не указал.

Comment: А еще лучше копируйте через `wcscpy`, а то у вас завершающий 0 не скопируется.